# xpath read root element

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to read a root element in my xml file. 
When i read it from XPath
`"beans/bean/......"`, it works fine. The XML input file begins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- The file defines all the configurations of the SemanticServer -->
<beans>
  <bean class="org.spr
```

but when I use as root element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```

instead of `<beans>` it does not work.

How can I read root element when it empty `<beans>` and not  `<beans xmlns="http` ......

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to read the root element beans or it's children bean? Oh and we need the code / xpath statement you are using. I'm guessing namespaces, but it is a guess.

Comment: for example, i have got bean <bean id = "mybean" and I want update bean's value beans/bean[@id='placeholderConfig']/property[@name='arguments']/value

Answer (score 2):

`/beans` in XPath 1.0 *always* means an element named "beans" that is not explicitly associated with any namespace. In the case of

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
```

the element is in the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` namespace, so you need to map that namespace URI to a prefix then use that prefix in your path expressions. How you do the prefix mapping depends on what tool you're using to interpret your xpaths. In XSLT, for example, it is sufficient to add an `xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"` to the root element of the stylesheet (not the input document), then you can do things like

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/b:beans/b:bean"/>
```